# How to fix infinite loop caused by dispatch function in TypeScript React and Redux code?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux, dispatch

I've written some React code using TypeScript that utilizes the useCallback hook and the dispatch function from Redux. Unfortunately, the code is causing an infinite loop, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Here's my code:

```
const onSelect = useCallback(
  (
    event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLDivElement, Event>,
    property: keyof OperationsDefinition
  ) => {
    const customEvent = event as unknown as CustomEvent;
    const options = customEvent.detail.options;
    const value = options.length ? options[0].id : "";

    dispatch(
      setEditedElement({
        ...(editedElement as Element),
        [property]: value,
      })
    );
  },
  [editedElement?.hierarchyScopeId]
);
```

calling:

```
{data && editedElement && (
  <DropdownHierarchy
    onSelect={(event) => {
      onSelect(event, "hierarchyScopeId");
    }}
    search
    configuration={{
      data,
      selectedElementsIds: [
        editedElement.hierarchyScopeId,
      ],
    }}
  />
)}
```

DropdownHierarchy is external component and I can't edit it.

When I call the onSelect function, which is passed to the DropdownHierarchy component, the code falls into an infinite loop and call onSelect and rerender all the time. It seems like the problem comes from using the dispatch function, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Could someone help me diagnose this problem and suggest a fix?

Comment: Is the external component open source? If so, linking to it would help. Or sharing its code.

Comment: No, it is not open source but I can show you onSelect function:


```
  #onSelect() {
    const { data } = this.configuration;

    const options = this.selectedItems.map((item) =>
      findElement(data, "id", item)
    );
    this.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent("select", {
        detail: { options },
        ...customEventsProps,
      })
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [React docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback) for useCallback:

> `dependencies`: The list of all reactive values referenced inside of the fn code. Reactive values include props, state, and all the variables and functions declared directly inside your component body. If your linter is configured for React, it will verify that every reactive value is correctly specified as a dependency. The list of dependencies must have a constant number of items and be written inline like [dep1, dep2, dep3]. React will compare each dependency with its previous value using the Object.is comparison algorithm.

Based on this information, your dependencies list is missing values.

As an aside, infinite loops are often caused by a missing conditional statement in a useEffect function.

Comment: I think conditional statement is applicable just for useEffect. Never had seen it in useCallback. Like when you click a button you expect effect to run unconditionally.